# Xcode 6 Swift - Displaying a local PDF

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pdf, swift

I wanted to be able to display a local PDF in my app but couldn't find an effective method to do so. I have already tried creating a Webview and downloading the PDF each time the app runs, but I would like for the app to display a local version. I found multiple tutorials on YouTube, however, they were all in Objective-C. Here are the links (in objective-c) of something similar to what I'm trying to do:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtKoddECri0&spfreload=10
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgu8HbTsY1M

I'm new to programming in general, so it would be great if your steps would be as detailed as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

1.Inside your Storyboard ViewController add Web View from Object Library

2.Right Click on Web View and drag & drop new referencing layout to your swift class , give some meaning full name (e.g..pdfWebView)

3.Inside View Controller add below code to load local PDF :

```
 var pdfLoc = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PDF_file", ofType:"pdf")!) //replace PDF_file with your pdf die name
 var request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfLoc);
 self.pdfWebView.loadRequest(request);
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

I looked at other posts on this forum, but wasn't able to resolve the issue. Can you please help me out?

Comment: The following error also came: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I have the same error. It crashes on the first line. I know the file exists on my Desktop. Do I type the whole file name with extension?

Comment: @softwareisfun The above command would get the file from your application's bundle, not from the file present in your desktop. You can copy the file to your project and pdfLoc variable would then be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

the same within WKWebView programatically:

```
let wkWebView: WKWebView = {
    let v = WKWebView()
    v.disableAutoresizingMasks()
    let pdfURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PDF_file", ofType:"pdf")!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: pdfURL)
    v.loadRequest(request)
    return v
}()
```

Comment: don't forget to import WebKit